# Haskell recursive function with if else block

Tags: haskell, if-statement, recursion

Hi I am new to Haskell and getting this error in my function doSomething

> Unexpected semi-colons in conditional:
>          if (solveMaze
>                (x + 1) y ex ey arr wasHere correctPath) then do { replaceNth
>                                                                     correctPath
>                                                                   !! x y True;
>                                                                   return True }; else Nothing
>      Perhaps you meant to use -XDoAndIfThenElse?

I have looked up on indentation and everything seems to be correct.

Below is my code

```
replaceValue n newVal (x:xs)
     | n == 0 = newVal:xs
     | otherwise = x:replaceValue (n-1) newVal xs

doSomething :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [String] -> [[Bool]] -> [[Bool]] -> Bool
doSomething x y a b arr visited correct = do
 if (x == a && y == b) 
  then do return True   
  else if (arr !! y !! x  == 'A' || visited !! x !! y == True) 
   then do return False  
   else do
    replaceValue visited !! x y True   
    if (x /= 0) 
     then do 
      if(doSomething (x-1) y a b arr visited correct) 
       then do
        replaceValue correct !! x y True
        return True
       else do 
        Nothing   
     else if (x /= length arr !! 0) 
      then do  
       if(doSomething (x+1) y a b arr visited correct) 
        then do
         replaceValue correct !! x y True
         return True
       else Nothing   
     else if (y /= 0) 
      then do 
       if(doSomething x (y-1) a b arr visited correct) 
        then do
         replaceValue correct !! x y True
         return True
        else Nothing   
     else if (y /= length arr) 
      then do
       if (doSomething x (y+1) a b arr visited correct) 
        then do
         replaceValue correct !! x y True
         return True
        else Nothing   
     else Nothing
    return False
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to post your actual code; this stripped down version doesn't contain the error.

Comment: Is this error showing up when compiling in GHC or when loading it in GHCi?

Comment: You're coming from an imperative world, aren't you? `replaceValue` doesn't work as you might expect, `return` doesn't do what you think it does, and the type checker is going crazy.

Comment: Please add some comments to your code explaining what you think it should do. Nobody here has any context for what you're doing, and the code as written does not make any more sense to us than it does to your compiler.

Comment: I am trying to implement [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm#Recursive_algorithm) algorithm. After I fixed the indentation issue, I am getting Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `m0 Bool.

I am new to Haskell and functional programming in general so I am not too sure how return works for functions. The 2 first ints I am passing are starting points, second 2 are ending points, [String] is my maze, and the 2 bool arrays are 2d arrays.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in this part of the code

```
   if(doSomething (x+1) y a b arr visited correct) 
    then do
     replaceValue correct !! x y True
     return True
   else Nothing
```

The last `else` should be indented more than the `if`. One extra space should be enough.

Still, your code has several issues. You are using a lot of `do`s around, but the type for your function does not use any monad. My suggestions:

- You seem to stick to using the same code structure you would use in imperative programming, which are typically cumbersome to translate into a functional language. Perhaps you should start learning Haskell doing basic exercises first. [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) is a popular tutorial website for this.
- For this specific code, you want a bidimensional array of `Bool`s. You model that using a list of lists, but this will lead to poor performance if you need random access to this array. I would use [vectors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) instead, since they offer quick random access.
- I can't clearly understand what your function is trying to perform. If a stateful program using a mutable vector is indeed the most natural choice, I would use the `State` monad, or the `ST` monad, to code this. Before starting to use monads, however, I would strongly recommend to achieve a solid understanding of the basics of the language. LYAH explains monads only in chapters 12 and 13, and rightly so.

I am suggesting this because code such as

```
do replaceValue .....
   return True
```

looks meaningless in a functional world: it seems to be trying to "modify" something in the array, which is not meaningful in non imperative languages. Without using monads, one could rewrite your function as

```
type Grid = [[Bool]]  -- or vectors...
doSomething :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [String] -> Grid -> Grid -> (Grid, Bool)
```

note that the final output is no longer a `Bool`, but a pair of said `Bool` and the new `Grid` with the intended modifications.

Comment: I am trying to implement [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm#Recursive_algorithm) algorithm. After I fixed the indentation issue, I am getting Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `m0 Bool.

I am new to Haskell and functional programming in general so I am not too sure how return works for functions. The 2 first ints I am passing are starting points, second 2 are ending points, [String] is my maze, and the 2 bool arrays are 2d arrays.

Comment: @BobTheBuilder `return` is unfortunately named because it is very different from `return` in C and similar languages. In Haskell, `return` is actually a function that takes a value and "puts it" into a "monadic value" (to use the terminology a bit loosely). What that ultimately means doesn't matter right now though. For now, you could think of it as turning a `SomeType` value into an `m SomeType` value (which is why you don't need it here). An example of a possible `m` would be `IO`, so we might have `return` turning an `Int` into a `IO Int` (for example). It "wraps" a type in some way.

Comment: Another important thing to realize is that, in Haskell, "variables" have are actually constant: once they are bound to a value, that value never changes. This takes some getting used to but like anything else, it just takes practice. Instead of changing a variable (which you can't do), you give it to a function which gives you an updated version (say you have an `x` and you give it to `(+ 1)` to obtain the value `x + 1`). Then you can pass that to another function (`f (x + 1)` for example).

Comment: So, where you might do something like this in an imperative language `... x = x + 1; f(x) ...`, you would do something like this in Haskell `... f (x + 1) ...` (this is a simplification of the general case, but it might give you an example of how the Haskell style differs). When you get right down to it, each Haskell program is only one function call with other function calls nested in it (and so on). That makes it sound more intimidating than it actually is though, because you can break it down into smaller functions.